# From Flash to Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, flash

I have a flash file, but I haven't got the source codes.

How can I get values from it?

For example if it was a html form, I can get the posted values like below:

```
Request.Form("myValue")
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get the posted values?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is really vague.  What kind of values were you hoping to pull?  What type of data do they contain?  How do you normally access them in Flash?  Any specifics at all would help.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, this code:

```
Request.Form("myValue")
```

Is not accessing the HTML source code; it's accessing the data sent in an HTTP form post.  In HTML, the `input` names happen to dictate which form variables are sent.

ActionScript (the Flash programming language) can do a post just like HTML.  Here's some sample code:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourpage.aspx");  
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();  
variables.myValue = "foo"; 
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleCompletion);  
loader.load(request);  

private function handleCompletion(e : Event):void {  
    // Do things after the post completes
}
```

If you post to an ASP.NET page or handler using this code, `Request.Form("myValue")` would work the same way as if an HTML form had been posted.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, that is to say, I have some mistakes from another parts, but can I retrieve the value with Request.Querystring function?

Comment: Yep.  To do that, you'd use `request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET` instead, and the variables would be translated to query string variables.